# How to copy one branch to other in Git

Tags: git, github

I have a branch with name `A` on which I have my running project. I have a friend who is working on branch `B`. Recently we did the major version changes in our source code, so the branch `B` is now up to date. I need to copy all the source code and files/folders to my branch so that branch `A` is sync with `B` and is also up to date. As I do not have much idea about git commands I simply thought of pulling the branch by using commands:

```
git checkout B
git pull origin B
```

Now after these two commands, all the changes of `B` was in my branch `A`. But then when I switched back to my branch by using `git checkout A`, everything reverted back. All I want is to copy all the content of `B` to `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With these to commands:

```
git checkout B
git pull origin B
```

you:

- switched to branch `B`
- synchronized the local state of branch `B` with it's remote state

When you run `git checkout A` you changed the working copy - `A` and `B` have different history - thus different files.

What you need to is to [merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) branch `B` into `A` or [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) it. If you are a git beginner better option is merge:

```
git checkout A
git merge --no-ff B
```

`--no-ff` will add a merge commit even if the merge is a *fast-forward*.

Answer (score 1):

You have to merge the branch B to branch A. The commands are:

`git checkout A
git merge B`

You can also rebase if the branch A is not pushed to the server.

I suggest you to learn how to manage branches on git. Here are two great tutorials that may help you https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow
https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do it in the following way.

```
git checkout B
git pull origin B
git checkout -b B_backup
git push origin B_backup

git checkout A
git pull origin A

git checkout B
git rebase -i A
```

(solving conflicts, check if everything works)

```
git push origin B -f
```

(this will overwrite branch B, be sure that there are no changes appeared there)

```
git push origin A:B
git checkout A
git pull origin A
```